# How to solve this issue? Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I'm beginning with c++ and I don't understand how to solve this issue :

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";


    string str ("Teststring");
    cout << str.end() << endl;//HERE
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you really need to know the *ending iterator* of a string?

Comment: `std::string::end` returns an iterator, for which no `operator <<` overload exists. If you want to print the last character in the string try `std::string::back`.

Comment: .end() returns const_iterator which cannot be outputted. Also using namespace std directive should not be used as it could cause conflicts in further development.

Comment: The way to solve this is to *learn C++* - It may take a few years, but you'll get there. I recommend starting with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you want to know the memory location which `str.end()` points to then `cout << (void *)s.end()._Ptr << endl;`

Comment: ok thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. `str.end()` will give unexpected behaviour - it returns an iterator *starting at the character after the end of the string*.
2. Try replacing the last line with `std::cout << str.c_str() << endl;` and you'll be making progress.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ for more.  The pointer/iterator is actually unnecessary, so `std::cout << str << endl;` will work just as well.

Comment: Why would you use `c_str()` here??

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: Good question.  No good excuse.  Old habits, too many years of C, immersion in pre-2005 Cpp, too much legacy CString, BSTR, wchar_t* etc - and not a helluva lot of attention to detail when firing off snap answer to newbie question.  I've updated my answer.